# iterate through cells with class name in DataTables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable named results.   1 column has select dropdowns which all have a class of contracts.   When the table is populated, I need to have all those select boxes be checked to assure they have a value greater than 0.   I need this to happen on ALL rows and not just the visible ones.

The following works, but only on the visible page:

```
jQuery(".contract").each(function() {
    id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    val = jQuery("#"+id).val()
console.log("Preparing to check "+id+" with a value of "+val+"\r\n");
    if(val==0) {
        validation(false, 'Required', 'div_'+id, 'input_'+id, false);
    } else {
        validation(true, '', 'div_'+id, 'input_'+id, false);
    }
})
```

Any insight on how to get the remainder of the pages to also use this block would be appreciated.  I am using the FREE version of DataTables.

UPDATE:

ok, I can get to the cells using the following:

```
table.column(5).nodes().to$().each(function(index) {
//  jQuery(".contract").each(function() {
    var cell = table.cell(this).data();
    id = jQuery(cell).attr('id');
})
```

Within each cell is a select box with the following HTML:

```
<div id="div_player_20">
     <div id="input_player_20">
        <select id="player_20">
            <option value="0" disabled="disabled">-- None --</option>
            <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Lifetime</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">7 Year</option>
            <option value="3" disabled="disabled">6 Year</option>
            <option value="4" disabled="disabled">5 Year</option>
            <option value="5" disabled="disabled">4 Year</option>
            <option value="6" disabled="disabled">3 Year</option>
            <option value="7" disabled="disabled">2 Year</option>
            <option value="8" disabled="disabled">1 Year</option>
            <option value="9" disabled="disabled">Minor League</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to get the selected value from each dropdown (including those that are off the screen)

Comment: When say 'All' rows, do you mean the rows on subsequent pages?  Those rows don't actually exist yet, so you will need to use the [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) event to run the code after each page is rendered.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct though because I can do similar with a change event by simply using the following jQuery("#results").on("change", ".contract", function() {

Comment: Can't you just read the data object that paints the data table to begin with?

Comment: I ended up going a different route since I could not figure this out.   I instead created a custom attribute (In the cell id itself) and changed it as the selection was made.